# using selenium/chromedriver to loop through multiples pages of a url and download the html for each page of the url

Tags: python, for-loop, format, selenium-chromedriver, range

I have a blog website with multiple pages of posts on the website. I need to loop through each of the pages on the website and download the html code for each page and store it in a list.

I am using Chromedriver to open each website. So far I have tried to use the range function to loop through the total number of pages (16)

```
from selenium import webdriver
import os
import time
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

list_88 = []
for i in range(17):

    chromedriver_path = os.getcwd() + '/chromedriver'
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
    driver.get('https://eller.arizona.edu/departments-research/centers-labs/entrepreneurship/news-events/news?page=0')
    link_url = driver.find_element_by_tag_name('a')
    time.sleep(10)
    html = driver.page_source
    list_88.append(html)
    driver.close()
```

However when I run this code it opens the same page over an over and downloads the same html. I know I need to specify (i) somewhere in the for loop so that a different page is opened each time, but I am not too familiar with chromedriver. I tried appending:

```
driver.get('https://eller.arizona.edu/departments-research/centers-labs/entrepreneurship/news-events/news?page=0').format(i)
```

But I get the error message:

```
'NoneType' object has no attribute 'format'
```

When I was using requests.get I used something similar:

```
for i in range(15):
    url = "https://eller.arizona.edu/departments-research/centers-labs/entrepreneurship/news-events/news?page=0"
    reqs = requests.get(url)
```

And this worked for me but, I would like to use chromedriver to do this. Any ideas how I can loop through multiple pages from one url and download the html from each page of the url to a list?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did not correctly format your url. It should be:

```
# add curly brackets as a placeholder for i
driver.get('https://eller.arizona.edu/departments-research/centers-labs/entrepreneurship/news-events/news?page={}').format(i)
```

This is the code that works for me for cycling through pages:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument('-start maximized')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)

for i in range(17):
    driver.get('https://eller.arizona.edu/departments-research/centers-labs/entrepreneurship/news-events/news?page={}'.format(i))
    time.sleep(2)
``
```

Comment: Hi Timothee, thanks for the help. I am still getting a 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'format' error even when I try using the curly brackets as a placeholder for i. Are you able to reproduce my code on your machine?

Comment: I updated my answer to include code that cycles through the pages. I tested this and it works.

Comment: This worked for me! Thank you for working to help me, I appreciate it.